# Why is Access requesting a parameter value when running SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Select count([Customer Number])
From
(
    SELECT distinct [Customer Number] & [Membership Number], [Customer Number]
    FROM Data
    Where [Customer Number] = 2000004
)
group by [Customer Number] & [Membership Number];
```

Looking for a parameter value of Membership Number. Why is this?

Comment: I.e. the subquery returns no [Membership Number], but still you're trying to access that column in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fields available to the outer `SELECT` are those which are listed in the subquery `SELECT`.  That subquery field list does not include `[Membership Number]` as a separate field. It's only there as part of an expression which concatenates 2 fields.  Access will assign an alias (like "Expr" followed by a number) to that calculated column. And it does not return a column named `[Membership Number]`.

Here is an Immediate window example which illustrates the issue ...

```vb
strSubQ = "SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Number] & [Membership Number], [Customer Number] FROM Data"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSubQ)

' what are the names of the fields available from the subquery?
For i = 0 To (rs.Fields.Count - 1): ? rs.Fields(i).Name : Next
Expr1000
Customer Number
```

So when Access sees `[Membership Number]` in the outer query's `GROUP BY` clause, it can't find that name in the available fields, and therefore assumes it must be a parameter.